# SQL View with cte Won't Save

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and have come across a problem creating a View. I have the following code:

```
;WITH
    cteSample
    AS (
                    SELECT
                            vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.SJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob DisplayMJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF
                          , 0 AS LVL
                    FROM vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub
                    WHERE vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF = 'True'
                    UNION ALL
                            SELECT
                                    vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.SJob
                                  , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                                  , CASE S.LVL
                                            WHEN 0 THEN S.SJob
                                            ELSE S.DisplayMJob
                                            END AS DisplayMJob
                                  , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF
                                  , S.LVL + 1
                            FROM cteSample S
                            INNER JOIN vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub
                                    ON S.SJob = vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                            WHERE vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF = 'False'
            )
SELECT
    cteSample.SJob
  , cteSample.DisplayMJob MJob
  , cteSample.GroupF
FROM cteSample
ORDER BY
    cteSample.LVL
  , cteSample.MJob
  , cteSample.SJob
```

This code executes fine as a query. When I execute as a View I get the message:

"Unable to parse query text"

When I Ok the code executes fine. When I try to save, I get the following error and it won't save:

"Incorrect syntax near ';'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `create view` in your statement - but it sounds as if you are confused by the usage of the statement terminator `;`. It needs to go at the end, not *before* the `with` statement.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, views should not contain ORDER BY clauses http://jes.blogs.shellprompt.net/2010/02/25/views-and-order-by/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ; before WITH is a common practice to avoid confusion when statement before CTE doesn't have a ; and that is causing syntax error

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: yes. But it's illegal in front of the `with` if that is part of a `create view`. Instead of putting the statement terminator in front of a `WITH` it would be a **much** better to always put it at the *end* of all statements (and this question shows how confusing this habit can be - it seems that user2849560 assumes the keyword is actually "called" `;WITH`, not `WITH` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create your view with `WITH` in the definition of the view. Simply remove the separator `;` (you don't need it anyway as `WITH` is your first and only statement) and `ORDER BY` (you should order when using the view):

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
WITH
    cteSample
    AS (
                    SELECT
                            vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.SJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob DisplayMJob
                          , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF
                          , 0 AS LVL
                    FROM vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub
                    WHERE vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF = 'True'
                    UNION ALL
                            SELECT
                                    vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.SJob
                                  , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                                  , CASE S.LVL
                                            WHEN 0 THEN S.SJob
                                            ELSE S.DisplayMJob
                                            END AS DisplayMJob
                                  , vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF
                                  , S.LVL + 1
                            FROM cteSample S
                            INNER JOIN vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub
                                    ON S.SJob = vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.MJob
                            WHERE vw_JobCosting_WIPMasterSub.GroupF = 'False'
            )
SELECT
    cteSample.SJob
  , cteSample.DisplayMJob MJob
  , cteSample.GroupF
FROM cteSample
```